# Animate text fill from left to right

Tags: css, background-image, fill

I wanted to animate a the text fill with CSS. The Text should be filled with color from left to right.

this is my CSS:

```
.box-with-text {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, crimson 50%, white 50%);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-animation: stripes normal forwards ease-in-out;
    animation: stripes 2s normal forwards ease-in-out;
}
```

Now only the first letter is color-filled.

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xta0x9w9/)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking for with the vague description paired with that fiddle. What's wrong with the demo you've provided? What's different between the fiddle and your goal? What limitations are there? If you're just looking to have the red 'grow' from left to right, then you're on the right track. Look at the code and see what you can do to make the red increase in size as opposed to working with a '`translate`' (sliding)

Comment: You're close.  Try playing with the settings.  I got a number of different effects by tweaking background-position, size, and animation duration.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xta0x9w9/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may also take a look at flex (for centering things) and `mix-blend-mode`, so it can be avalaible also for Firefox:

```css
.box-with-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 26vmax/.8 Open Sans, Impact;
  background: black;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply
}

@-webkit-keyframes stripes {
  to {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes stripes {
  to {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}

html {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
      -ms-flex-align:center;
          align-items:center;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( crimson , crimson) turquoise no-repeat 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient( crimson , crimson) turquoise no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  -webkit-animation: stripes 2s linear infinite;
          animation: stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-with-text">
  Text
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XKNKzd

Comment: this looks great. How to do it with white text getting filled?

Comment: @Rubocop do you mean white to crismon ? you need to add a background-color ex http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YWpWmj white, but could be any other color even another gradient  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EyNgYv

Comment: can you help me again.
how does this work with a transparent background in .box-with-text?
http://codepen.io/rubocop/pen/KMNgQa

Comment: @Rubocop do you mean : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VjmKoo if yes, remove background-color (aside gradient)

Comment: I mean, that just to get the text filled from white to crimson

Comment: @Rubocop sorry, i do not understand, looks to me that it actually does (from left to right)

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Main styles */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);

.box-with-text {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, crimson 50%, white 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 100% 200px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation: stripes 2s linear infinite;
  animation: stripes 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes stripes {
  100% {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
  }
}

@keyframes stripes {
  100% {
    background-position: 385px 0;
  }
}
/* Other stuff */
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.box-with-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 26vmax/.8 Open Sans, Impact;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-with-text">
  Text
</div>
```

In this case you should change

```
@keyframes stripes {
  100% {
    background-position: 385px 0;
  }
}
```

position depends on text width;