# Text color fill from left to right with created html element on creation

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, fill

hi guys i need a little bit help im total confused. I have JS script, which highlights at a specific time a line of text and changes the class to highlighted. What i want to do is add a text fill/color text change effect from left to right i tried to implement it from here [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952222/animate-text-fill-from-left-to-right)

Dont know what i do wrong on changing the class to highlighted it should start to animate.
here are the files and code

css rule original for highlighted

```
body .content .test > div.highlighted {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;

}
```

js to generate the highlighted div element

```
function generate() {
   var html = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < _data["test"].length; i++) {
      html += "<div";
      if(i == 0) {
         html+=` class="highlighted"`;
         currentLine = 0;
      }
      if(_data["test"][i]["note"]) {
         html += ` note="${_data["test"][i]["note"]}"`;
      }
      html += ">";
      html += _data["test"][i]["line"] == "" ? "•" : _data["test"][i]["line"];
      html += "</div>"
   }
   $(".test").html(html);
   align();
}
```

and the html which is generated from js

```
<div class="highlighted">Lorem ipsum donna wetta</div>
```

could need some help really didnt knwo what i do wrong all the time should be simple but isnt.
Thanks

Comment: include the html please

Comment: @Scaramouche inserted the html